# Set the same property to several same objects (and not repeat)?

Tags: c#, windows-8

Is there any solution how to simplify this code? I just want to set same property in several objects of same type. These objects are TextBoxes in Windows 8 app. I think it could be something with Array and foreach... but am not sure
Thanks

```
private void makeVisible(int x)
        {
            if (x == 1)
            {
                field2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                field3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                field4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                field6.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                field8.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                field9.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                field11.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

            if (x == 0)
            {
                field2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                field3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                field4.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                field6.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                field8.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                field9.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                field11.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                errorReporter.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add the fields to a List, and loop through the List to change the properties.

Comment: I'd just use an Array literal in code, but share the sentiment...

Comment: If you're building a WinRT app using C#, chances are you should be using the MVVM pattern and simply binding all these fields' Visibility property to some shared member in the View Model. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can at least do is the following:

```
var visibility = x == 0 ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;

field2.Visibility = visible;
field3.Visibility = visible;
// etc
```

If you want to work with an array, you can even do the following, but I'm not sure whether this is an improvement:

```
foreach (var obj in new[] { field1, field2, field3 ... })
{
    obj.Visibility = x == 0 ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void makeVisible(int x)
{
    var boxes = new TextBox[] { field2, field3... };
    foreach (TextBox box in boxes)
    {
        box.Visibility = (x == 1) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    if (x == 0)
    {
        errorReporter.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyFieldType> fields=new List<MyFieldType> {field2, field3, field4, field6, field8, field9, field11};

foreach(MyFieldType field in fields)
   {
   if(x==1)
      {
      field.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
      }
   else if(x==0)
      {
      field.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
      }
   }
```

Use a collection to store your objects and iterate over it.

Answer (score -1):

You definitely need to loop through the elements as answered above, but you don't have to build the list manually, use `Reflection` to simplify this:

```
this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(pi=>pi.PropertyType == typeof(TextBox))
```

Comment: This is a *not* good practice in any way. Not only is Reflection opening up a whole set of assumptions about performance and security, it's also the sort of naive code that will suddenly start changing random textboxes you forgot you had that had nothing to do with the original problem.